# The button effect only works after the function ends

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events

On my sidebar, there are two buttons `button1` and `button2`. What I want is, after `button1` is clicked then `myfunction()` will run simultaneously `button2` is disabled. When `myfunction()` ends, `button2` switches to enable state. I used the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        google.script.run.myfunction();
            $("#button1").attr("disabled",true);
            $('#button2').attr("disabled", false);
        });
    });
});
```

However, when `button1` is clicked, the function `myfunction()` runs and `button2` is also enabled. This causes the user to click `button2` while the function is running, resulting in an error. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well is `google.script.run.myfunction();` asynchronous? Sounds like it is so you would beed to use a promise to wait for it to be done. Hopefully the code returns a promise

Comment: There is a syntax error in the code extra ```});``` at the last line. Remove them and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for `Promises`. Use [async-await](https://javascript.info/async-await) to achieve this.

`google.script.run.myfunction` should be an async call.

Disable your button before the function is run. Then in the second line, we wait for the result from `myfunction` execution. Later, we toggle the `disabled` attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(async function(){
            $("#button1").attr("disabled",true);        
let newVal = await google.script.run.myfunction();
            $('#button2').attr("disabled", false);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks **Tushar Shahi**, for giving me one more very interesting function. However, with the code as you suggested it still doesn't solve the problem. That is, the effect of `button2` is still active immediately (Although I left out a }); for excess.)